# I was trying to send data from one activity to next activity but when it goes to next activity it is only diplaying toast not data

Tags: android, android-activity

I was trying to send data from one activity to next activity but when it goes to next activity it is only displaying toast and no data

```
  tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    Bundle data=getIntent().getExtras();
    String marks=data.getString("TotalMarks");
     result.setText(marks);
```

Comment: did you checked the key value, are they both same ?

Comment: Can you post the code for sending the data from Activity 1 to the second

Comment: show the code how you are setting the value in bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you send data through the Intent like that:

```
intent.putExtra("TotalMarks", "String to send");
```

And retrieve it :

```
intent.getStringExtra("TotalMarks");
```

Be careful, the key is case sensitive!